# How to sync a CoreData table with an online resource?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a list of items on my server of which my app has a copy in CoreData.

One of my web APIs downloads the up-to-date list.

I've successfully wrote code that updates columns, and adds new rows/items to my local CoreData storage.  Here's the code for processing an item received from server ("name" uniquely identifies a row, assume `Object` is the entity):

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", dictionary[@"name"]]];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object"
                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

error = nil;
ObjectData* object = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
//### Handle error.
if (object == nil)
{
    object = (ObjectData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
}

object.name  = dictionary[@"name"];
object.place = dictionary[@"place"];
...

error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
//### Handle error.
```

The above code does sync existing and new items from server to CoreData.  However, rows that were deleted on the server are not being deleted from CoreData.

What is an efficient way to sync deletions?  Note: The `Objects` have relationships, so simply removing the whole lot and adding them again won't work.

For example, how do I form a query that removes all rows who's name is not in the up-to-date list that was downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server data always represents the complete table, don't worry about synch logic, just replace the client data.

If it's truly a synch situation, consider using a "soft delete".  Add a "deletedAt" date column to your server and client tables and synch that, too.  Qualify the client queries as you have them, but add deletedAt != nil.  Every so often (on both client and server) remove rows where deletedAt is older than some old date.

An added benefit of this is the ability to undo a delete sometime before the old date threshold you set.

Alternatively, to find objects in your data that are not in the loaded objects:

```
NSArray *names = // the array of names in the newly loaded data
NSPredicate *deletedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (name IN %@)",names];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  The app does not need such a "soft delete" because the real data is on the server.  So this would add unnecessary work & complexity.  Do you perhaps know how I could form a query that would delete all items with names that are not in the newly loaded list of names?

Comment: That kind of query sounds doable, but how are you assured that a missing name in the newly loaded list really represents a delete?  Maybe it just didn't appear in the query result.  If the answer is "the newly loaded list always represents the whole table", then you don't need any synching logic at all.  Just replace the client data with the newly loaded list.

Comment: Yes, the loaded list is always complete.  How do I 'replace' the client list, other than by deleting the old first?  I'm worried that this deletion will break relationships.  Ah but wait, with your `deletePredicate` I'm seeing the light!  Yes, that's it, thanks!